# c++ back_insert using wrong,

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> square_vec(const vector<int>& v)
{
    vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(v.size());
    back_insert_iterator< std::vector<int>> back_it (result);
    transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_it, [](int i)  
            {   
                return i*i;
            }); 
    return result;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> my_vec = {1 ,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    vector<int> result_vec;
    result_vec = square_vec(my_vec);
    return 0;
}
```

I got error like this, tried different things. not working yet.
please help. thanks!

```
test_transform.cpp: In function â€˜std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > square_vec(const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)â€™:
test_transform.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜[â€™ token
test_transform.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜]â€™ token
test_transform.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜intâ€™
```

my g++ is  4.4.7-4
then I tried 4.8.1 it works.
thank you all.

Comment: Does your compiler support lambda expressions? That is what the error appears to be about. The `[]` starts a lambda, the compiler seems surprised to see it.

Comment: In fact your code compiles and runs successfully in a capable C++11 compiler.

Comment: Your code works as it is (http://ideone.com/00Dj1g) What is your compiler version? How are you compiling it?

Comment: First step, fix your console, it doesn’t support Unicode.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please answer your own question. That's how SO works.

Comment: You should include `<iterator>` anyway. That is where `std::back_insert_iterator` lives. You can't rely on it being included indirectly via other headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per request, answering the topic:

Your compiler doesn't support Lambda expressions.  The errors you're seeing start with the brackets, `[]`, on line 10. (@Daniel)

Try changing your compiler to see if that helps - your compiler must support C++11.